# Is there a Java Library for the Klarna Payments API?

Tags: java, klarna

We want to offer our customers the chance to pay with klarna, we would use a Hosted Payment Page and the Klarna Payments API to do this:

https://docs.klarna.com/hosted-payment-page/

https://docs.klarna.com/api/payments/

The trouble is, it's all a bit complicated and I would normally expect a company like Klarna to offer us a java library where everything is given to me and I just create the objects.

Here's their github

https://github.com/klarna

If I search for java in the repositories I get one result that is halfway relevant:

https://github.com/klarna/kco_java

but this is marked as deprecated and is klarna checkout and not klarna payments anyway.  The suggested replacement repository is then a 404 error

https://github.com/klarna/kco_rest_java

The email address is no longer in use, they don't respond to a support ticket for over a week, if I google "klarna payments api java implementation", the fourth result is called "PaymentsOrdersApi (kco-rest 3.0.3 API)", which is also a 404 error.......

https://klarna.github.io/kco_rest_java/v3.0.3/com/klarna/rest/api/payments/PaymentsOrdersApi.html

Do they really have no java implementation for their API?  I'm confused by the 404 errors, surely they want it to be easy to use their product, but I can't get a hold of them to ask anything.

Comment: If they don't respond to support tickets, and their email isn't in use, why would you trust that their API still works? And even if it still works _today_, why would you trust that their API still works next week?

Comment: Because the customer will pay us to implement it!

Comment: Then just use the http api. Asking for libraries here is off-topic anyway.

Comment: If you're getting paid to do this, then surely you can read through the API docs and write only what you need as generic "authed http calls" using an off the shelf library for making authed API calls.

Comment: Sure, and I will, but why shouldn't I look to see if there is a library that will save me substantial time.

Comment: you could try the konfigthis.com sdks ([here](https://github.com/konfig-sdks/klarna-payments-java-sdk), and [here](https://github.com/konfig-sdks/klarna-checkout-java-sdk)), but like @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans said, I think the best way would be to work with the REST API directly, either with Java's `HttpURLConnection` or an external library like `Apache HttpClient`, `OkHttp`, or `Retrofit`.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/